# Hop Rhizomes in South Africa

Tags: hops, rhizome

I want to use home-grown hops in my home-brewed beer. And the best way I can think of doing that is to grow my own hops.

The only problem is that I can't seem to find any suppliers of hop rhizomes in South Africa. Even all the hops farms in the country are owned by SAB.

Does anyone know anywhere that sells the female hop rhizomes that can ship internationally? I'm looking for Cascade specifically, but will take others as well.

I've tried growing them from seeds, but have failed each time.

Comment: Please I also need hop Rhizomes. I live in limpopo and have all the adequate lights and space. Please let me know who i can call. Thanks

Comment: Atron (commented below) is planning on trying to get some from abroad.

Comment: Did you try contacting local homebrew clubs?  Maybe someone has a root they can cut for you.  Pretty trivial operation, so it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Very few American hop farms ship to SA because we are in the Southern Hemisphere. You also need a importers license. The license is cheap, but it requires that the company sending the items to you have a certificate that the hops is clean (not infected with any bugs from the importers list).

You might want to try NZ or Australia.

I was going to get a few rhizomes from USA this year, but I found out about the "cleanliness" too late. Will be better organized next year.

DO NOT IMPORT THEM ILLEGALLY! Some bugs from overseas can and will kill the SA hops.

I can try to get South African rhizomes for you. Is there a specific type that you are looking for?

Comment: Are you (1) also in South Africa? and (2) still going to get some next year?

Comment: (1) yes, Jhb. (2) Yes, if all goes to plan.

Comment: Awesome! Maybe before you order/smuggle/mule/import, we can arrange to get a few extra? (How do i contact you on this site? can't find a link)

Comment: There is no way to PM another user. I got your email from your blyzz registration details. and sent you emails.

Comment: Did you guy's manage to get hops plants? I can help, I have a few varieties available, I'm just north of Pretoria. gert.vdwaal@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not recommended to import due to diseases. However, I would suggest reaching out to SABmiller and ask if you can get a few rhizomes next time they do their root "pruning" (I can't think of the correct term.)
From what I've heard they're very homebrewer friendly.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look into that!

Comment: You are right Shelby. One of their head brewers is also an avid home brewer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried contacting SAB Miller and I got a flat "no we don't do that" response from them so I suppose overseas is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Hop rhizomes are, to the best of my knowledge, not available from any regular supplier in South Africa. However, some home brewers occasionally have a few (not sure where from) and might be willing to share. Asking the Wort Hog Brewers and similar home brewing clubs (they've pretty much all got Facebook pages) is probably your best bet.

As others have already pointed out, importing and exporting hop rhizomes is difficult due to international regulations on moving plants across borders. The South African customs service is especially difficult (not to say stupid) in this regard; I've imported plastic bottle draining trees that were held at customs for agricultural inspection. I'm serious - that's what they did.

Good luck!